# How convert the new code to an extension including a new database table

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I have customised the Magento application to include **COD** & **expected date** of delivery.

That is I have included a new DB table and change in `/app/design/themeFolder`.

Now how can I convert this to extensions and include it to Magento connect?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @NitinPawar Thank you. This link was really usefull. Let me try with this.